# How to print a table in python/flask

Tags: python, flask

In my `flaskblog.py` file i have following dictionay:

```
facts = [
{   'logo': 'img/hex.png',
    'exchange':'binance',
    'link': 'https://binance.com',
    'volume': '345789',
    'users24h': '23456'
},
{   'logo':'img/wolf.png',
    'exchange':'kucoin',
    'link': 'https://kucoin.com',
    'volume':'123458000',
    'users24h': '17000'
},
{   'logo':'img/wolf.png',
    'exchange':'hitbtc',
    'link': 'https://hitbtc.com',
    'volume':'345890',
    'users24h': '500'
}
]
```

in my `eth.html` file i have following:

```
{% extends "layout2.html"%}
{% block content%}
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">


    <table id="dtBasicExample" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm" cellspacing="0" width="80%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Logo</th>
                <th>Exchange</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>volume</th>
                <th>Users 24h</th>
            <tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for fact in facts %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ fact.logo }}</td>
                <td>{{ fact.exchange }}</td>
                <td>{{ fact.link }}</td>
                <td>{{ fact.volume }}</td>
                <td>{{ fact.users24h }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    
    {% endblock content %}
```

When i run it it only prints out the table headings like: Logo, exchange, link etc.. but not actually the content of the dictionary

How can I fix this?

I tried

Comment: Are you adding the `facts` in the `render_template` view function as a parameter?

Comment: no, i didnt  and thatswhy it didnt work- thanks dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a dictionary to html file, not an object. You will have to refer to them with following notation just as you refer a normal dictionary with its keys:

```
<tbody>
{% for fact in facts %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ fact['logo'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ fact['exchange'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ fact['link'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ fact['volume'] }}</td>
         <td>{{ fact['users24h'] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Have you passed the `facts` dictionary to the file?

Comment: no i didnt do that, now it works- but why does fact.link and fact.volume work but not fact.users24h? when i changed it to fact['users24h] it works- whats the difference?

Comment: but why arent the links clickable?

Comment: You just have inserted values from dictionary in the table cell. For them to be clickable as link, you need to surround it with `<a>` tags. For `users24h`, it might not be working because variable contains numbers and letters both, but inserting in quotes refers to that particular key that you are referring.

Comment: got it thanks- however i have a last question since you already here: I use mdbootstrap for the table design but it doesnt render correctly like the search bar etc dont show up and once i have more than in my case 10 items the page doesnt become scrollable

Comment: i also have a footer and with more items, the items are printed below the footer

Comment: I think you should post a new question for this purpose, which will be more focused on that topic and code that associates with it and image of what you might be getting. Its difficult to explain here.

Comment: ok, well i can only post every 90 minutes- thanks for this question, hopefully you have time later to take a quick look on my isue later, thx for your help so far dude